# Kafka Clients jar JAVA

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to learn kafka.The zookeper server and kafka and installed on a ubuntu AWS node.Zookeper server in running along with three brokers and a consumer.I am using java client(kafka-clients0.9.0.1) in my maven project(on my laptop) to send the data to brokers and consumer on aws.

Is it necessary to have zookeeper and kafka running on my local system to connect to kafka on aws?
I have windows 10 on my local system.

While connecting to Kafka cluster the broker shows the following>
INFO Closing socket connection to /xx.xx.xx.xx due to invalid request: Request of length 1195725856 is not valid, it is larger than the maximum size of 104857600 bytes. (kafka.network.Processor)

Comment: No, It's not at all needed. That's where clients come into picture. The only thing you should have is access to Kafka server.

Comment: Hi ,I have zookeper server(within kafka directory), three brokers and a consumer for a topic running on aws. But my client code(local machine) is unable to send data to consumers.What might be the issue?

Comment: see difference between Kafka Broker, Kafka Producer and Kafka Consumer here: 1. Kafka Broker(Server) is original Kafka server which holds data 2. Kafka Producer(Client) is one of Kafka clients which sends data to Broker 3. Kafka Consumer(Client) is also one of Kafka clients and which consumes data from Kafka Broker(Server). Can you check your producer has access to Kafka? like port is opened or not?

Comment: Yes. I am able to telnet on that port. (telnet XX.XX.XX.XX 9042).Also all the Inbound/Outbound TCP ports are open on that node.

Comment: Whenever I am trying to connect to kafka using client I get this error.
 INFO Closing socket connection to /122.172.32.10 due t                                                                                        o invalid request: Request of length 1835863306 is not valid, it is larger than                                                                                         the maximum size of 104857600 bytes. (kafka.network.Processor)

Comment: Good there is some progress. Can you look at this issue which may help you to resolve the above error. http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/157c4wy00q/stunning-error-request-of-length-1550939497-is-not-valid-it-is-larger-than-the-maximum-size-of-104857600-bytes

Comment: Thanks for the link but it doesn't give any solution.

Comment: Solved the problem.Setting advertised.host.name =PublicIP,advertised.port=9092 in server.properties did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by making two new entries in server.properties file which the broker is using.

advertised.host.name = PublicIP(of aws node)

advertised.port=9092

Comment: Have you configured "host.name" & "port" properties before adding this?